# python list items switch not working

Tags: python

I am trying to define a switch function as part of the MarblesBoard class which will switch my first two numbers around:

```
class MarblesBoard:
    def __init__(self, marbles):
        self.input = marbles 
    def switch(self):  
        list(self.input)[1], list(self.input)[0] = list(self.input)[0], list(self.input)[1]
        print list(self.input)                    

board = MarblesBoard((3,6,7,4,1,0,8,2,5))
board.switch()
```

The answer must be dead simple but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `list(self.input)`, you create a new list separate from self.input . It's unsurprising that when you've modified the list, the original tuple referred by self.input remains unchanged.

Instead, (as one isn't able to modify a tuple), you may keep you board content as a list (instead of tuple) all the time:

```
class MarblesBoard:
    def __init__(self, marbles):
        self.input = list(marbles) 
    def switch(self):  
        self.input[1], self.input[0] = self.input[0], self.input[1]
        print (self.input)
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you do this:

```
list(self.input)
```

You're *creating a new list*. If you don't assign it to a name, it's thrown away.

How about this:

```
class MarblesBoard:
    def __init__(self, marbles):
        self.input = list(marbles)
    def switch(self):  
        self.input[1], self.input[0] = self.input[0], self.input[1]
        print self.input
```

Create a list from the user's input at just one point, then internally work with just that.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you type `list` you're creating a brand new list.  So when you have `list(self.input)[0] = ...` you're making a totally new list, setting its 0th item to a new value, then throwing that new list away since it's not getting stored anywhere.  You need something like:

`self.input[1], self.input[0] = ...`